# Создание в основном коде ссылки на дочерний

Tags: python, tkinter

Получился большой код, в котором сложно ориентироваться, можно ли разделить его на несколько отдельных участков, положить в отдельные файлы, и при запуске основного кода ссылаться на них?

Comment: если вас интересует вопрос можно ли это сделать, то да можно. Просто импортуруйте файл с другим кодом в основной.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, не могли бы вы показать реализацию этой функции на простом примере в коде?

Comment: попробуйте сузить вопрос. Вы не знаете как можно использовать функции из другого модуля в Питоне? Пример: [Как можно в linux-консоли обратиться к ТОЛЬКО ОДНОЙ функции в python-файле?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/833453/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Ну для примера 2 файла

`xay.py`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import quest

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Какой текст из основного файла").pack()
        button = tk.Button(self, text="кнопка", command=quest.Top).pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().mainloop()
```

и `quest.py`:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Top(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Текст который изображен в другом файле").pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Top().mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо)