# Как можно в linux-консоли обратиться к ТОЛЬКО ОДНОЙ функции в python-файле?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, функции, bash

Хотелось бы реализовать что-то типа "python3 проект.py --функция", и выдавалось только то содержимое, что было в функции?

```
def func():
    print("Hello, World!")
def func2():
    print("World, Hello!")
```

И затем

```
$ python3 файл.py *колдовство, обращение только к функции func2*
```

Вывод был таким:

```
World, Hello!
```

Comment: в скрипт из командной строки можно передать аргументы и, в зависимости от аргументов, изменять поведение скрипта

Comment: Запустить из командной строки скрипт типа *python3 -c 'import file; func2()'*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю такое решение:

```
import sys

def func():
    print("Hello, World!")

def func2():
    print("World, Hello!")

name = sys.argv[1]
f = globals().get(name)
if f:
    f()
```

Пример использования:

```
$ python file.py func
```

Если функции с указанным именем не будет, скрипт ничего не выведет.
Можете модифицировать его на вывод ошибки:

```
if f:
    f()
else:
    print('No such method: %s' % name)
```

Answer (score 5):

Если у вас есть `module` модуль, определённый в `module.py` файле, расположенный в одной из [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) директорий ([текущая директория](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044) включена в pythonpath для `-c`), то чтобы вызвать функцию `function` из этого модуля:

```
$ python -c 'import module; module.function()'
```